# Get a count of a number of records with same create date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table containing records all with a create date. I want to Select all the records created in January 2014 and have a count of how many were created each day. I've gotten as far as Selecting all the records created that month but I'm unsure how to proceed to get an output of all the days that month and a count of how many records were created.

```
SELECT TYPE
,PART_ID
,DESIRED_QTY
,RECEIVED_QTY
,CREATE_DATE
FROM WORK_ORDER
WHERE DATEPART(year,CREATE_DATE) = 2014 and DATEPART(month,CREATE_DATE) = 01
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE ASC
```

The information I'm selecting in that statement isn't important, it's just there in that query so I'm selecting something.

Comment: group by CREATE_DATE before order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  It is an aggregation query that does the count:

```
SELECT CAST(CREATE_DATE as Date) as date,
       COUNT(*)
FROM WORK_ORDER
WHERE DATEPART(year, CREATE_DATE) = 2014 and DATEPART(month, CREATE_DATE) = 01
GROUP BY CAST(CREATE_DATE as Date)
ORDER BY CAST(CREATE_DATE as Date) ;
```

The `CAST()` is only needed if `CREATE_DATE` could have a time component.  The reason this query uses `CAST()` is so the same structure will work on multiple months.

I want to add, that it is better to write the query like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CREATE_DATE as Date) as date, COUNT(*)
FROM WORK_ORDER
WHERE CREATE_DATE >= '2014-01-01' and CREATE_DATE < '2014-02-01'
GROUP BY CAST(CREATE_DATE as Date)
ORDER BY CAST(CREATE_DATE as Date) ;
```

The difference here is the `WHERE` clause.  This formulation can make use of an index on `CREATE_DATE`.  Your formulation has functions around the arguments, so it would not use the index.

Comment: Does order by work with group by -- Don't you need a sub-query?

Comment: @Hogan . . . `ORDER BY` is a separate clause and you can place it after `GROUP BY`.  This could also use `ORDER BY date`, taking advantage of the column alias defined in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Ok then that is just DB2 where you need a sub-query.

Comment: @Hogan . . . I'm pretty sure DB2 supports `ORDER BY` with `GROUP BY`.  I see no limitation in the documentation (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_selectclause.dita) and IBM basically invented the original SQL language that supports this.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and the explanation was well appreciated

Comment: @GordonLinoff - You are right, I went back and looked at when it wouldn't let me do it two weeks ago and that was because I had a case statement in the group by.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEPART(day,CREATE_DATE), count(*) 
FROM WORK_ORDER
WHERE DATEPART(year,CREATE_DATE) = 2014 and DATEPART(month,CREATE_DATE) = 01 
group by DATEPART(day,CREATE_DATE)
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a count by day, I suggest:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM WORK_ORDER
WHERE DATEPART(year,CREATE_DATE) = 2014 and DATEPART(month,CREATE_DATE) = 01
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, CREATE_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  DATE(CREATE_DATE) as day,
  COUNT(*) as count
FROM WORK_ORDER
WHERE DATEPART(year,CREATE_DATE) = 2014 and DATEPART(month,CREATE_DATE) = 01
GROUP BY DATE(CREATE_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEPART(year,CREATE_DATE), 
       DATEPART(month,CREATE_DATE), 
       DATEPART(day,CREATE_DATE), 
       count(*)
FROM WORK_ORDER
WHERE DATEPART(year,CREATE_DATE) = 2014 
and DATEPART(month,CREATE_DATE) = 01
group by DATEPART(year,CREATE_DATE), 
       DATEPART(month,CREATE_DATE), 
       DATEPART(day,CREATE_DATE)
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE ASC
```